# CSV to Snowflake - Converts some data to Uppercase Automatically

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format, import-csv

**Hello Techies,**

*Thanks for your time in reading this and trying to help.*

I have a peculiar situation where I have a CSV file with data (separated by commas) in an external stage. I have snowflake stored procedure, that accesses, reads this file, loads the data into a snowflake table.

Everything is good except, **Some of the data from the file gets automatically converted into Uppercase.**

My T-SQL in the procedure does not do any Transformation or Conversion of data to upper case.

The Optional parameters in the Snowflake File Format for CSV file type does not have any parameters to preserve the proper case or current case of data in the file.

Please help

***Thanks in advance.***

***Regards,
Sathya***

Comment: So just to be clear, in the raw CSV file the data is lowercase, but when you query it in snowflake it's represented as uppercase? I would use `DESCRIBE TABLE` to check the collation settings on the destination table. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/collation.html#collation-sql-constructs Maybe some columns are set to be case-insensitive?

Comment: CSV File's data is in both cases (upper as well as lower). But only certain cell values of few records are getting converted into Upper case. Not all the values in that column are getting converted into upper case.

Comment: It is actually not clear.  We don't know what the Procedure does.  We don't know how you are uploading the data into the table (other than "I have snowflake stored procedure, that accesses, reads this file, loads the data into a snowflake table.").   no clue what the data in the CSV file looks like.   There is not enough information to assist you with your problem. Provide some of the code/SQL that you are using to get better assistance.